# Unable to add reference from COM

Tags: .net, excel, com-interop

I am unable to select Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel from my window/assembly directory. I can see that one is there but it does not give me the option to reference it. How can i select it?

Answer (score 2):

Look on the COM tab and search for Microsoft Excel 12.0 / 11.0 Object Library.

Adding this COM reference will make your project use the primary interop assembly for Excel that should have been installed to the GAC.

Just make sure that you select the correct version, 11.0 for Excel 2003 and 12.0 for Excel 2007.